# PHP Code.... After query I need to Update the table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which filters a ranging dates and I got the results just fine. But after the query I am lost on how to update the table row that I want to changed.

It goes something like this

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['show'])){
    if (isset($_POST['startDate']))
    $startDate = strtoupper(trim(preg_replace("/[^0-9-]/", "", $_POST['startDate'])));// filter everything but spaces, numbers, and letters
    if (isset($_POST['dateEnd']))
    $dateEnd = strtoupper(trim(preg_replace("/[^0-9-]/", "", $_POST['dateEnd'])));// filter everything but spaces, numbers, and letters
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM enroll WHERE date >= '$startDate' AND date <= '$dateEnd' AND status = '0' ");
$DisplayList ="";
$enrollList = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($enrollList > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $status = $row['status'];
        $amount = $row['en_amount'];
    if ($status == 0) 
        $st = 'NOT ENROLLED';
        else
        $st = 'ENROLLED';
        $DisplayList .= "<strong>$st</strong><br />";//output the list request
    }
} else {
    $DisplayList = "PLEASE INPUT VALID ENTRIES";
}
}
?>
```

It display a list which is okay for me. The filter is (I think) good I have no problems with that. What I'd like to ask is from the previous query how can I update the status. I have this 'Update' button, and if the button is clicked I'd like to update the row 'status' from the range output of the previous query. I hope I have explained it well. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use [`UPDATE`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm) - And from the MySQL manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

Comment: what's the result you want while update status ?

Comment: The status would simply update as '1' on the MYSQL or 'ENROLLED' with that being said the next time I run the same date range the updated ones will not show as the condition with the list... oh and I have a button that is needed to be click in order for the update to happen. I hope I was able to explain this well. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Like **Fred -ii-** say - use UPDATE query:

```
$status = 1;
mysql_query("UPDATE enroll SET status = '$status' WHERE date >= '$startDate' AND date <= '$dateEnd' AND status = '0' ");
```